# Second os.walk runs extremely slow

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, os.walk

The program works perfectly however when it performs the second `os.walk` operation it takes significantly longer than the first time. So the first time the `os.walk` occurs it walks through the directory tree until it finds the directory with the name matching the `partno` input. It then stores the directory location as `path_to_files`. It then walks the given directory and opens all files that start with the `partno`. My guess is that even after finding the directory on the first `os.walk` it continues searching to make sure it doesn't find another matching directory. Like I said it works great but it seems to find the `path_to_files` directory almost instantly but then when it runs to open the files this takes significantly longer (8-15 seconds) is there something I am doing wrong in my code or does this have to do with attempting to open 3-6 files in different applications at once? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance...

```
import os

partno =""
partno = raw_input("Enter Part No:") #Takes user input of Part No
yourpath = r"Y:\SHOP\MANUFACTURING DOCS" #Parent directory
print ("Loading Part No %r files...Please wait") % partno

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(yourpath, topdown=True):
    for name in dirs:
            if name == partno: #Matches folder in directory to `part no`
                path_to_files = (os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name)))
                #Stores path in variable so files are only found in this folder
                print path_to_files #Confirmation line for me

for dname, _, fnames in os.walk(path_to_files, topdown=True):
    for fname in fnames:
        if fname.startswith(partno): 
            filepath = (os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dname, fname)))
            os.startfile(filepath) #Opens all files in folder in their native applications
            print filepath
    break

raise SystemExit
```

Comment: It seems reasonable to me that simply printing the filenames in a directory will happen significantly faster than running a bunch of applications in a directory...

Comment: Also, there really is no need to `raise SystemExit`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That was my assumption and I just ran a couple of tests and the other issue is it does not start opening the files until it searches the entire directory. I'll need to make it stop looking once the first `os.walk` finds a match.

Comment: Yeah, probaly you want your `break` statement inside the `if name == partno:`.

Comment: The second `os.walk` starts potentially many application instances through the OS, but the first just prints matching paths—seems fairly obvious to me. Comment-out your `os.startfile()` call and see how slow the second usage is then.

Comment: If using python < 3.5, *always*, install the `scandir` module.